# Prescriptions in checked luggage: ok when travelling to Spain?

Tags: air-travel, legal, luggage, health

Can I pack my physeptone tablets in my checked luggage instead of my hand luggage? I'm flying to Spain / Majorca and don't want the people I'm going with to see the medication.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say where you're flying from, but any time you put medication into your checked baggage you run the risk of it not being there when you reach your destination. This seems like a medication you might need to take regularly, and a medication that might get stolen, so I would caution against putting it into your checked baggage.

When I travel, I usually take a small first aid kit with me. It's an opaque cosmetics bag. Could you get something similar? Add some band-aids, some ibuprofen, and some Kleenex. Obviously no metal, like nail clippers, or anything else that would prompt additional screening.

Is there any way for you to select a separate screening line at the airport? If not, and you get pulled aside for extra screening, tell the rest of your party to head to the gate and you will meet them there.

Good luck to you. It's hard to maintain privacy while flying.

Comment: Thnks ever so much for your advice much appreciated x

Comment: My impression from Google is that that drug has street value--such a drug should never be checked.  Given the reality of airport security I would have it in something that's not too easy to open--locked or zip-tied shut.  That would also hide it from your traveling companions.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of where you're flying from and the possibility of being stolen at the source airport you are transporting a [controlled substance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methadone).  There are strict guidelinces in US, UK, Australia, and [Europe](http://ec.europa.eu/health/ph_projects/2003/action3/docs/2003_3_18_frep_en.pdf) with regards to [possession and transportation](http://www.emcdda.europa.eu/html.cfm/index146601EN.html) of this substance.

To my knowledge it's an opioid used as a withdrawal aid for Heroin addiction, so with that in mind drug sniffing dogs are very likely to find them, so unless you have bulletproof licensing to possess or transport this drug you should not try transporting it across borders prescription may not be enough.

Comment: +1 for the caution but I am not convinced that dogs would be very likely to find it, however. They don't magically detect active molecules, they are somewhat sensitive to the smell of specific products and they are not even *that* good at it. A pharmaceutical product is going to be chemically much purer (devoid of by-products and impurities found in street drugs) and properly sealed. Not a reason to take chances of course but what dogs can do should not be exaggerated.

Comment: @Annoyed You're welcome to try and pass through customs with a bag full of methadone tables and let me know how this goes.  The issue is that dogs are trained to detect opiates like heroine rather then byproducts otherwise using slightly different ingredients in manufacturing process will defeat the purpose.

Comment: I believe that this is neither true nor chemically or physiologically possible. Do you have any evidence for it?

Comment: @Annoyed http://people.howstuffworks.com/police-dog4.htm